# Sync Framework 2.1 - Is there a way to remote scope artefacts from database?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am currently upgrading an application that made us of sync framework 1 to version 2. As part of this I am using the new scoping system and dropping the use of SQL Server Change Tracking.

It would appear that in order to provision a remote database for sync framework a number of new tables and stored procedures must be created.

Is there a way, using the API, to remove these artefacts should they no longer be needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928603%28SQL.110%29.aspx

Remove a scope:

```
// Remove the retail customer scope from the Sql Server client database.
SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning clientSqlDepro = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(clientSqlConn);

// Remove the scope.
clientSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope("RetailCustomers");
```

Remove all sync metadata artifacts:

```
// Remove all scopes from the SQL Server Compact database.
SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning clientSqlDepro = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(clientSqlConn);
clientSqlDepro.DeprovisionStore();
```

If you use a custom schema and/or prefix for table names, don't forget to add these to the `SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning` object.